# iphone: performSelector: withObject: afterDelay: does not work with a background thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to run a method in a background thread, the first method will run another method on the same (background) thread after some seconds. I wrote this:

```
- (IBAction)lauch:(id)sender
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(first) withObject:nil];

}
-(void) second {
    printf("second\n");
}
-(void) first {
    NSAutoreleasePool *apool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    printf("first\n");

    [self performSelector:@selector(second) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

    printf("ok\n");
    [apool release];
}
```

but the second method is never called, why? and, how may i accomplish my goal?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to have a running run loop for performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: to work.

---

Your code executes `first` and, when `first` exits, the thread is gone.   You need to run a run loop.

Add:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

To the end of `first`.

Comment: ouch... no. That should be the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand, how can you not have a run loop?

Comment: I also don't get it. Can this answer be a bit more specific?

Comment: You have a run loop because they come with threads but nothing autonomously causes a run loop to run. You need to attach input (such as an `NSPort`) or a timer for that to happen. If you want a second run loop that just runs, it's common to hatch a thread that calls `runUntilDate:` on its run loop repeatedly until an exit condition occurs.

Comment: Is there a reason why the `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]` needs to be added to the end? I tried adding it before `performSelector` was called and it did not work. Adding it afterwards did the trick

Comment: Answered my own question: from the NSRunLoop documentation: `If no input sources or timers are attached to the run loop, this method exits immediately; otherwise, it runs the receiver in the NSDefaultRunLoopMode by repeatedly invoking runMode:beforeDate:. In other words, this method effectively begins an infinite loop that processes data from the run loop’s input sources and timers.` `performselector:afterdelay:` adds a timer to the current run loop. This needs to be done before calling `run`

Comment: @aidnoodle `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]` never returns.  You have to set everything up prior.